# EF Core query on Oracle View very slow

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework-core, .net-5

I have a .NET 5 WebAPI that is accessing an Oracle view using the Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore 5.21.1 package that is taking over 30 seconds to complete.

The query is simply trying to return all the rows from the view (8767 rows):

```
        public async Task<IEnumerable<Curve>> GetAllAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            var result = await _curveRepository.CurveDetails.ToArrayAsync(cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
            var time = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;
            return _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Curve>>(result);
        }
```

the code for the model builder is as follows

```
modelBuilder.Entity<CurveDetail>(entity =>
            {
                entity.HasNoKey();
                entity.ToView("MB_CURVE_DETAIL");

                entity.Property(e => e.Id)
                    .HasColumnType("NUMBER")
                    //.ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
                    .HasColumnName("CURVE_ID");

                entity.Property(e => e.Name)
                    .HasColumnName("CURVE");

                entity.Property(e => e.CurveContent)
                    .HasColumnName("CURVE_CONTENT");

                entity.Property(e => e.CurveContentId)
                    .HasColumnType("NUMBER")
                    .HasColumnName("CURVE_CONTENT_ID");

                entity.Property(e => e.CurveType)
                    .HasColumnName("CURVE_TYPE");

                entity.Property(e => e.CurveTypeDescription)
                    .HasColumnName("CURVE_TYPE_DESCRIPTION");

                entity.Property(e => e.CurveTypeId)
                    .HasColumnType("NUMBER")
                    .HasColumnName("CURVE_TYPE_ID");

                entity.Property(e => e.CurveValidTo)
                    .HasColumnName("CURVE_VALID_TO");

                entity.Property(e => e.BidOffer)
                    .HasColumnName("BID_OFFER");

                entity.Property(e => e.BidOfferId)
                    .HasColumnType("NUMBER")
                    .HasColumnName("BID_OFFER_ID");

                entity.Property(e => e.Contract)
                    .HasColumnName("CONTRACT");

                entity.Property(e => e.Contract1)
                    .HasColumnName("CONTRACT1");

                entity.Property(e => e.Contract1EndurName)
                    .HasColumnName("CONTRACT1_ENDUR_NAME");

                entity.Property(e => e.Contract1Id)
                    .HasColumnType("NUMBER")
                    .HasColumnName("CONTRACT1_ID");

                entity.Property(e => e.Contract1Name)
                    .HasColumnName("CONTRACT1_NAME");

                entity.Property(e => e.Contract1Type)
                    .HasColumnName("CONTRACT1_TYPE");

                entity.Property(e => e.Contract1TypeId)
                    .HasColumnType("NUMBER")
                    .HasColumnName("CONTRACT1_TYPE_ID");

                entity.Property(e => e.Contract2)
                    .HasColumnName("CONTRACT2");

                entity.Property(e => e.Contract2EndurName)
                    .HasColumnName("CONTRACT2_ENDUR_NAME");

                entity.Property(e => e.Contract2Id)
                    .HasColumnType("NUMBER")
                    .HasColumnName("CONTRACT2_ID");

                entity.Property(e => e.Contract2Name)
                    .HasColumnName("CONTRACT2_NAME");

                entity.Property(e => e.Contract2Type)
                    .HasColumnName("CONTRACT2_TYPE");

                entity.Property(e => e.Contract2TypeId)
                    .HasColumnType("NUMBER")
                    .HasColumnName("CONTRACT2_TYPE_ID");

                entity.Property(e => e.ExtractSettledProduct)
                    .HasColumnName("EXTRACT_SETTLED_PRODUCT");

                entity.Property(e => e.IsAheadCurve)
                    .HasColumnName("IS_AHEAD_CURVE");

                entity.Property(e => e.LiveDaysInvalidItem)
                    .HasColumnName("LIVE_DAYS_INVALID_ITEM");

                entity.Property(e => e.LiveMonths)
                    .HasColumnType("NUMBER")
                    .HasColumnName("LIVE_MONTHS");

                entity.Property(e => e.Location)
                    .HasColumnName("LOCATION");

                entity.Property(e => e.Measurement)
                    .HasColumnName("MEASUREMENT");

                entity.Property(e => e.MeasurementEndurName)
                    .HasColumnName("MEASUREMENT_ENDUR_NAME");

                entity.Property(e => e.MeasurementId)
                    .HasColumnType("NUMBER")
                    .HasColumnName("MEASUREMENT_ID");

                entity.Property(e => e.Pipeline)
                    .HasColumnName("PIPELINE");

                entity.Property(e => e.PzlId)
                    .HasColumnType("NUMBER")
                    .HasColumnName("PZL_ID");

                entity.Property(e => e.SettledCurveId)
                    .HasColumnType("NUMBER")
                    .HasColumnName("SETTLED_CURVE_ID");

                entity.Property(e => e.Zone)
                    .HasColumnName("ZONE");
            });
```

The query's execution time on oracle is around 100 ms. Does anyone have any idea what's taking the time? If I change the query to perform a count instead of returning the data it executes quickly.

The view is as follows:
[image: View definition]

UPDATE:

If I change the query to use select instead of AutoMapper as follows:

```
        public async Task<IEnumerable<Curve>> GetAllAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            return  await _curveRepository.CurveDetails.Select(x =>
                new Curve((long) x.Id)
                {
                    BidOffer = x.BidOffer, 
                    BidOfferId = (long) x.BidOfferId,
                    ContentId = (long?) x.CurveContentId, 
                    Contract1Id = (long) x.Contract1Id,
                    Contract2Id = (long?)x.Contract2Id,
                    CurveTypeId = (long)x.CurveTypeId,
                    PzlId = (long?)x.PzlId,
                    MeasurementId = (long?)x.MeasurementId,
                    LiveDaysInvalidItem = x.LiveDaysInvalidItem,
                    LiveMonths = x.LiveMonths,
                    SettledCurveId = (long?)x.SettledCurveId,
                    ValidTo = x.CurveValidTo,
                    //Content = x.CurveContent,
                    //Contract1Endur = x.Contract1EndurName,
                    //Contract1MadBase = x.Contract1Name,
                    //Contract2Endur = x.Contract2EndurName,
                    //Contract2MadBase = x.Contract2Name,
                    //CurveType = x.CurveType,
                    //Pipeline = x.Pipeline,
                    //Location = x.Location,
                    //Zone = x.Zone,
                    //MeasurementEndur = x.MeasurementEndurName,
                    //MeasurementMadBase = x.Measurement,
                    IsAheadCurve = x.IsAheadCurve.Equals('Y')
                }
            ).ToArrayAsync(cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
```

With the assignments to strings commented out the operation takes about 1 second. With the string assignments back it takes about 12 seconds.

This indicates that the bottleneck is related to the string operations.

Is there anything I can do to improve the performance.

Comment: What are the data types of the various columns in Oracle?  Are there any that are "special" (not simple `varchar2`, `date`, `number`, etc.)?  If things like 'location' are, say, a Spatial data type, that would be something to investigate.  Where is the 100 ms time coming from?  Are you tracing the actual query EF is generating?  Running a `select *` directly on the client?  Looking at `v$sql`?

Comment: I've added the view definition to the question. There are some varchar2 columns but no spatial data. The 100 ms time came from the DBAs profiling the query

Comment: The response time is base on a lot of factors including the database size.  The query has to search the entire database which can talk a long time.  Also the driver affects the time.  Usually with ORACLE you use the ODBC driver which is much quicker than the OLEDB driver.

Comment: Very possible there's a bug in EF5, but my guess would be it's related to that 4000 character CURVE column.  Try it without selecting that and see?

Comment: You specified HasNoKey. Do you really not have a Primary Key or other index on this table? If it's just an unindexed heap, then that is probably an underlying issue

Comment: I've updated the question with my latest findings. Everything is pointing to the strings being the problem and nothing to do with the indexes.